# Best answer contest: Third quarter of 5779

Tags: discussion, status-completed, answer-contest

Have you seen (or written) a recent answer on Mi Yodeya that you thought was really great? Let's have a contest to help you tell everyone about it!

This contest has two phases: Nomination and Voting. It is currently in the **Voting** phase.

1. **Nomination** - ended July 7, 2019

   Post an answer to this Meta post containing a link to the Mi Yodeya answer you want to nominate. Answers created in **Nisan - Sivan, 5779 (from April 6 through July 3, 2019)** are eligible.

   Please link to one answer in each entry. Nominate as many answers as you like in separate answers to this post.

   *When you see a great answer, don't wait; post a link to it here before you forget!*

   Please *do not* vote on any answers to this post during the Nomination phase.
2. **Voting** - July 8 - 14, 2019

   On July 8, this post was edited to indicate that the Voting phase has begun, and the [featured](/questions/tagged/featured) tag will be added.

   During this phase, everyone is invited to vote on the answers to this post however you see fit. Upvote (or downvote, I guess) as many as you like.

[image: 300-point Bounty button]

The answer linked in the highest voted answer to this meta post will receive a bounty of 300 points after completion of the event on July 14, 2019. In case of a tie, the distinction will be shared, and the prize will be split.

---

<sup>Concept and words borrowed from [Movies.SE](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2558/rewards-for-the-best-answer-from-the-4th-quarter-of-2016).</sup>

Comment: If you see any new great answers now, please nominate them in the [Fourth Quarter contest](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5157/best-answer-contest-fourth-quarter-of-5779), already in progress.

Comment: Locked to end voting

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[הנער הזה](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/5083/%d7%94%d7%a0%d7%a2%d7%a8-%d7%94%d7%96%d7%94)'s [answer](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/104556/2) to [Where in Tanach is Shavuot associated with Matan Torah?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/16659/where-in-tanach-is-shavuot-associated-with-matan-torah) addresses a simple question of general interest by bringing a myriad of sources to bear, organized nicely into three general approaches. Each source and idea is written up clearly and cited/linked competently, leading to a document that engages the reader from beginning to end, exposes dozens of ideas, and provides hooks for branching off into more learning. This is an ideal form of Mi Yodeya answer.

Answer (score 2):

I would like to nominate [my answer](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/104442/13438) to [Did Rabbi Joseph Albo say the mitzvoth will be abolished?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/101602/did-rabbi-joseph-albo-say-the-mitzvoth-will-be-abolished) The question seemed to be a simple question of "Did X say Y?", but it languished for two months with no answer. My answer cited a dozen or so passages from the work of the author in question, across various volumes and chapters, to provide a nuanced answer to what had seemed like a pretty black-and-white question.

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to nominate @[user15464](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/15464/user15464)'s answer to ["Which mishnah in Shas has the most daf between it and the subsequent mishnah?"](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/103319/18474)

Not an easy answer to find and put together (ie not Google-able) and definitely required serious time and effort in compiling the list.