# Best Answer Contest winners! Second quarter of 5779

Tags: discussion, status-completed, answer-contest

Congratulations and *Yeyasher Kochachem* to [Alex](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/13438/alex) and [sam](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/1418/sam), the co-winners of the [Best Answer Contest for the second quarter of 5779](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4845/best-answer-contest-second-quarter-of-5779)!

Here are the original citations, submitted by [mbloch](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/users/11501/mbloch) and [DoubleAA](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/users/759/double-aa), respectively:

> I would like to nominate [Alex's](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/13438/alex) [answer](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/98390/11501) to [How long was the period of Oppression](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/75610/11501) which, in a near-essay, brings together multiple historical sources, factoids and wonderful writing to answer an age-old question.

and

> I'd like to nominate [sam](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/1418/sam)'s [answer](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/99310/759) to [Is using hair removal cream on one's face a violation of "rounding one's beard?"](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/99303/759) A picture is worth a thousand words, and all the more when demonstrating historical positions. It's hard to imagine ever giving a Shiur on this topic again without showing off these photos of a rare artifact. Thank you sam!

The winning entries will split the 400-point bounty prize.

[Best answer contest: Third quarter of 5779](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5118/best-answer-contest-third-quarter-of-5779), covering  *Nisan - Sivan, 5779 (from April 6 through July 3, 2019), is ***already underway***. If you see a new great answer, please nominate it!

Comment: Curious - I didn't pay attention to what you do during leap years, such as this one, where there are 13 months. Did you make each quarter 3.25 months long, or you placed both Adars in the 2nd quarter?

Comment: @DanF This was the first time. We made this "quarter" 4 months long. See Footnote 2 [here](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4845/best-answer-contest-second-quarter-of-5779).