# Best answer contest: First quarter of 5780

Tags: discussion, status-completed, answer-contest

Have you seen (or written) a recent answer on Mi Yodeya that you thought was really great? Let's have a contest to help you tell everyone about it!

This contest has two phases: Nomination and Voting. It is currently **over**. Alex's [last-minute nomination](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5269/2) won by default.

1. **Nomination** - ends January 1, 2020

   Post an answer to this Meta post containing a link to the Mi Yodeya answer you want to nominate. Answers created in **Tishrei - Kislev, 5780 (from September 30 through December 28, 2019)** are eligible.

   Please link to one answer in each entry. Nominate as many answers as you like in separate answers to this post.

   *When you see a great answer, don't wait; post a link to it here before you forget!*

   Please *do not* vote on any answers to this post during the Nomination phase.
2. **Voting** - January 1 - 6, 2020

   On January 1, this post will be edited to indicate that the Voting phase has begun, and the [featured](/questions/tagged/featured) tag was added.

   During this phase, everyone is invited to vote on the answers to this post however you see fit. Upvote (or downvote, I guess) as many as you like.

[image: 300-point Bounty button]

The answer linked in the highest voted answer to this meta post will receive a bounty of 300 points after completion of the event on January 6, 2020. In case of a tie, the distinction will be shared, and the prize will be split.

---

<sup>Concept and words borrowed from [Movies.SE](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2558/rewards-for-the-best-answer-from-the-4th-quarter-of-2016).</sup>

Comment: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/109342/759 if you want. doesn't stand out for sources but perhaps for presentation

Comment: it's short, but i'm proud of it https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/110420/759

Comment: Still no nominations yet?

Comment: Is the voting phase open yet? (Granted there’s only one submission...)

Comment: Is there a second quarter post?

Comment: @DonielF Sorry; do you have a nomination you want to post?

Comment: I do indeed. Whenever you get a chance. (It _is_ still second quarter, right?)

Comment: @DonielF Sorry about the extended delay. Here it is: https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5283/best-answer-contest-second-quarter-of-5780

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would like to nominate [my answer](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/108821/is-anyone-against-the-rational-teachings-of-maimonides/108823#108823) to [Is anyone against the rational teachings of Maimonides?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/108821/is-anyone-against-the-rational-teachings-of-maimonides)

The question asked if anyone opposed the rational teachings of Maimonides, and my answer provided a wide array of objectors on various different topics.