# Best Answer Contest winner! Fourth quarter of 5779

Tags: discussion, status-completed, answer-contest

Congratulations and *Yeyasher Kochacha* to [Oliver](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/5083/%D7%94%D7%A0%D7%A2%D7%A8-%D7%94%D7%96%D7%94), the winner of the [Best Answer Contest for the fourth quarter of 5779](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5157/best-answer-contest-fourth-quarter-of-5779)!

Here is the original citation, submitted by [Alex](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/users/13438/alex):

> I would like to nominate [Oliver](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/15571/oliver)'s [answer](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/64303/authorship-of-mevo-hatalmud/107126#107126) to [Authorship of Mevo Hatalmud](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/64303/authorship-of-mevo-hatalmud). This question had languished for nearly four years without an answer, and Oliver's answer collected various sources in modern scholarship to provide an approach to the topic.

The winning entry will receive the 300-point bounty prize.

[Best answer contest: First quarter of 5780](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5217/best-answer-contest-first-quarter-of-5780), covering  Tishrei - Kislev, 5780 (from September 30 through December 28, 2019), is ***already underway***. If you see a new great answer, please nominate it!