# Best answer contest: Second quarter of 5780

Tags: discussion, answer-contest

Have you seen (or written) a recent answer on Mi Yodeya that you thought was really great? Let's have a contest to help you tell everyone about it!

This contest has two phases: Nomination and Voting. It is currently in the **Nomination** phase.

1. **Nomination** - ends March 29, 2020

   Post an answer to this Meta post containing a link to the Mi Yodeya answer you want to nominate. Answers created in **Tevet - Adar, 5780 (from December 29, 2019  through March 25, 2020)** are eligible (yes, including in-season [Purim Torah](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/797/purim-torah-policy-allowed-but-regulated) answers).

   Please link to one answer in each entry. Nominate as many answers as you like in separate answers to this post.

   *When you see a great answer, don't wait; post a link to it here before you forget!*

   Please *do not* vote on any answers to this post during the Nomination phase.
2. **Voting** - March 29 - April 5, 2019

   On March 29, this post will be edited to indicate that the Voting phase has begun, and the [featured](/questions/tagged/featured) tag was added.

   During this phase, everyone is invited to vote on the answers to this post however you see fit. Upvote (or downvote, I guess) as many as you like.

[image: 300-point Bounty button]

The answer linked in the highest voted answer to this meta post will receive a bounty of 300 points after completion of the event on April 5, 2020. In case of a tie, the distinction will be shared, and the prize will be split.

---

<sup>Concept and words borrowed from [Movies.SE](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2558/rewards-for-the-best-answer-from-the-4th-quarter-of-2016).</sup>

Comment: Voting period??

Comment: @DonielF Sorry; been distracted

Comment: So, um. What's happening with this contest?

Comment: I second @DonielF's comment

Answer (score 1):

I’d like to nominate [Heshy’s answer](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/111227/) to [my question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/111224/). In under twenty minutes he took the initiative to hack together some Python code to compile the entire Shas Mishnayos and sort by initial letter of each Mishnah. Tizku l’Mitzvos, thank you for your tremendous help, and may we never know more sorrow.

Comment: **Please don't vote on any answers until the Voting phase begins.**

Comment: Amen and thank you!  There was some serious siyata dishmaya at play here.  I usually need a lot more iterations of debugging before my code works.

Comment: אתה אומר ובלע המות לנצח וגו׳ והיכן דבר אני אמית ואחיה וגו׳

Comment: @Dr.Shmuel אמית בעולם הזה ואחיה בעולם הבא

Answer (score 1):

I think [this](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/111828/9215) answer form Robev is very valuable, because it contains references to comments not well known, as the comment of Rabbi Avraham Abulafia.

Such answers are helpful for learning. Links are very allow to get texts quickly.