# Why is this old, historically locked question without the featured tag showing up in the community bulletin?

Tags: support, community-bulletin-board

[This question](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5157/best-answer-contest-fourth-quarter-of-5779?cb=1) was featured one year ago, and was unfeatured and historically locked in October 2019.

However, it is showing up in the community bulletin sidebar today:

[image: Bulletin]

Why is this non-featured question suddenly mistakenly showing up in that block?

[Meta.SE report](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/353351/why-did-a-question-suddenly-become-featured-when-the-last-edit-was-almost-a-year), where a moderator here has reported that there has been no activity on the question since it was locked.