# Best Answer Contest winner! Third quarter of 5779

Tags: discussion, status-completed, answer-contest

Congratulations and *Yeyasher Kochacha* to [הנער הזה](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/5083/%D7%94%D7%A0%D7%A2%D7%A8-%D7%94%D7%96%D7%94), the winner of the [Best Answer Contest for the third quarter of 5779](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5118/best-answer-contest-third-quarter-of-5779)!

Here is the original citation, submitted by [Isaac Moses](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/users/2):

> [הנער הזה](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/5083/%d7%94%d7%a0%d7%a2%d7%a8-%d7%94%d7%96%d7%94)'s [answer](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/104556/2) to [Where in Tanach is Shavuot associated with Matan Torah?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/16659/where-in-tanach-is-shavuot-associated-with-matan-torah) addresses a simple question of general interest by bringing a myriad of sources to bear, organized nicely into three general approaches. Each source and idea is written up clearly and cited/linked competently, leading to a document that engages the reader from beginning to end, exposes dozens of ideas, and provides hooks for branching off into more learning. This is an ideal form of Mi Yodeya answer.

The winning entry will receive the 300-point bounty prize.

[Best answer contest: Fourth quarter of 5779](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5157/best-answer-contest-fourth-quarter-of-5779), covering  *Tamuz - Elul, 5779 (from July 4 through September 29, 2019), is ***already underway***. If you see a new great answer, please nominate it!

Comment: wow thanks so much everyone!